# Re-sample df to microsecond - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to re-sample timestamps in a df to display every 0.1 seconds. It is re-sampling but I'm losing the data relative to those timestamps.

```
d = ({   
    'Time' : ['2010-07-27 09:25:31.1','2010-07-27 09:25:31.2','2010-07-27 09:25:31.4','2010-07-27 09:25:31.5','2010-07-27 09:25:31.6','2010-07-27 09:25:31.9','2010-07-27 09:25:32.0'],
    'Area' : ['A','A','A','A','A','A','A',],
   })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df = df.set_index('Time').asfreq('0.1S').reset_index()
```

Out:

```
                     Time Area
0 2010-07-27 09:25:31.100  NaN
1 2010-07-27 09:25:31.200  NaN
2 2010-07-27 09:25:31.300  NaN
3 2010-07-27 09:25:31.400  NaN
4 2010-07-27 09:25:31.500  NaN
5 2010-07-27 09:25:31.600  NaN
6 2010-07-27 09:25:31.700  NaN
7 2010-07-27 09:25:31.800  NaN
8 2010-07-27 09:25:31.900  NaN
9 2010-07-27 09:25:32.000  NaN
```

Intended:

```
0 2010-07-27 09:25:31.100  A
1 2010-07-27 09:25:31.200  A
2 2010-07-27 09:25:31.300  NaN
3 2010-07-27 09:25:31.400  A
4 2010-07-27 09:25:31.500  A
5 2010-07-27 09:25:31.600  A
6 2010-07-27 09:25:31.700  Nan
7 2010-07-27 09:25:31.800  NaN
8 2010-07-27 09:25:31.900  A
9 2010-07-27 09:25:32.000  A
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do as follows.
First you need to make sure your column is in `datetime64[ns]` & then use `resample` on that column

```
df['Time']=pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
df.set_index('Time').resample('0.1S').last().fillna(0).reset_index()
```

**Output**

```
                       Time     Area
0   2010-07-27 09:25:31.100     A
1   2010-07-27 09:25:31.200     A
2   2010-07-27 09:25:31.300     0
3   2010-07-27 09:25:31.400     A
4   2010-07-27 09:25:31.500     A
5   2010-07-27 09:25:31.600     A
6   2010-07-27 09:25:31.700     0
7   2010-07-27 09:25:31.800     0
8   2010-07-27 09:25:31.900     A
9   2010-07-27 09:25:32.000     A
```